# Objective c: Sliding?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uikit

I'm not really sure what's this called, but I'm working on a game that involves basically catching a falling object, or image, by holding your finger on it and then flicking it upwards. How would I code an image view to respond to my finger to basically change it's position on the screen.

I'm pretty new to iOS programming I don't even know where I would start

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at Apple's [MoveMe](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MoveMe/Introduction/Intro.html) sample project. It does exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Well, without the "flicking it upward" part. But it's a relatively small step from having all your gestures set up and a view tracking with user touches to the flicking part.

Answer (score 1):

Objective-C is the language, Cocoa Touch is the framework that deals with touches and image views and such. Changed tags to match.